# Typescript Types declaration not found

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, types, discord.js, type-declaration

I was programming a small Discord bot in TypeScript when I encountered an issue with my types declaration file.

index.d.ts:

```
declare module 'configuration' {
    /**
     * Configuration of your bot.
     */
    export type IConfiguration = {
        /**
         * Token of your bot.
         */
        token: string
        /**
         * Prefix of your bot.
         */
        prefix: string
        /**
         * Time to cool down the bot commands.
         */
        coolDown: number
    }
    /**
     * Context at which we are logging.
     */
    export type IContext = '[Bot]' | '[Client]' | '[Server]'

    /**
     * Type for the commands
     */
    export type ICommand = (message: Message, arguments: string[]) => void | any 
}
```

Apparently index.ts is not capable of loading the declarations file?

Doing `import { IConfiguration, ICommand } from 'configuration';` only returns the error:
`Cannot find module 'configuration' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

I've been looking online, some of the solutions mentioned listing your types in package.json and tsconfig.json, but none of them seemed to help.

TSConfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "allowJs": true,
      "checkJs": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "target": "es2015",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      // TBD it is desired to enabled strict type checking at some point:
      "strict": false,
      "typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"]
    }
}
```

I've got no idea why this is not working. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found out what was happening.

Apparently ES Module `import` and typescript `declare module` are not very good friends... not sure why it didnt wanna work, but when I exported all the types to root level:

```
/**
 * Type for the commands
 */
export type ICommand = (message: Message, arguments: string[]) => void | any 

/**
 * Context at which we are logging.
 */
export type IContext = '[Bot]' | '[Client]' | '[Server]'

/**
* Configuration of your bot.
*/
export type  IConfiguration = {

    /**
    * Token of your bot.
    */
    token: string

    /**
    * Prefix of your bot.
    */
    prefix: string

    /**
    * Time to cool down the bot commands.
    */
    coolDown: number
}
```

It worked just fine. If anyone knows why is this happening let me know please!